# Real life application of Fibonacci search technique

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I was wondering how the Fibonacci search method applied in real life. Does it have any examples?

Answer (score 1):

For an application in clinical oncology (choosing doses in drug testing), see [this paper](https://ascopubs.org/doi/10.1200/JCO.2003.99.058).